# How to "emulate" admin login?

Tags: c#, api, console-application, yammer

Using this call directly in the browser i am able to invite a user to a Yammer group:

GET https://www.yammer.com/insert_yammer_network_name/group_settings/process_additions/isert_groupID.json?id=isert_groupID&invites[ids][]=&invites[emails][addresses]=insert_email@domain.com&auto_add_invitees=true&authenticity_token=insert_oauth-token

I get the following response:

```
{"status":"ok"}
```

However it only workes when i am logged in with the admin user in the same browser.
When i try doing the same thing from a Console application I get 406.

EDIT: Other calls work perfectly with the token i have, and without the need to be logged in with the admin user. I believe my browser stores admin user credentials as cookies and then allow the call. The thing is, that my call needs the admin to verify that users can have access to that particular group.

Comment: send the oauth token along with your request.  You won't be authenticated from your console application without credentials.

Comment: I already have my oauth token in the header?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [OAuth authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), take a look at the [Yammer .NET SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#winphone-sdk) part **OAuth In .NET SDK**